# Draw line over candle chart on amchart

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am using [amchart stock chart](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart)

```
function createStockChart() {
    var chart = new AmCharts.AmStockChart();
    var dataSet = new AmCharts.DataSet();

    // make candlechart

    dataSet.fieldMappings = [{
        fromField: "open",
        toField: "open"
    }, {
        fromField: "close",
        toField: "close"
    }, {
        fromField: "high",
        toField: "high"
    }, {
        fromField: "low",
        toField: "low"
    }, {
        fromField: "volume",
        toField: "volume"
    }, {
        fromField: "testValue",
        toField: "testValue"
    }];
    dataSet.dataProvider = chartData;
    dataSet.categoryField = "date";


// make line to be drawn on the candle stock

    var dataSet2 = new AmCharts.DataSet();
    dataSet2.fieldMappings = [{
        fromField: "close",
        toField: "value"
    }];
    dataSet2.color = "#33888a";
    dataSet2.dataProvider = chartData;
    dataSet2.compared = false; // if I made here true, the line appears but it will be shown as percentage!!.
    dataSet2.title = "Open";
    dataSet2.categoryField = "date";
```

I would like to draw a line over the candle chart.

If I use `true` for `compared` field, the line appears over the candle part, but  Y axis turns to the percentage.

That's right becuase it is for comparing function.

However I want to append the graph simply not for comparison.

How can I simple draw a line on candle chart???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set [`recalculateToPercents`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockPanel#recalculateToPercents) to `"never"` in your panel object to prevent the chart from using percents and just add the line. This is explained in more detail in [the knowledge base](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/disabling-or-enabling-value-axis-recalculation-to-percents/)

Here's a [fiddle that illustrates this](http://jsfiddle.net/okpt6dzn/1/). It uses the JSON setup, but the object-based setup is similar.